# Summing elements from a copied array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sum

I've written a program that creates a restaurant menu through a text file, is opened up in another program and used to create a customer order.

I have a function which is needed to create the total amount at the end however the total sum is never produced, the program instead produces the total from `itemPrice * itemQuantity` and prints that instead of summing the final total.

I have the items saved in the `menuItem` array and am trying to copy them into a `billingItems` array to sum the prices in parallel. What step am I missing in order for `total` to sum up the prices, so `total` at the bottom would equal 44 (16+28) ?

Thank you

Creating the order in main():

```
int main(){
    int i;
    Item billingItem[MAX_ORDER];
    Item menuItem[MAX_ORDER];
    int itemNumber;
    int itemQuantity;
    int billOpt;

    std::ofstream transactionFile;
    transactionFile.open("transactionFile.txt");
    int count = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_ORDER; i++) {
        std::cout << "Item number: ";
        std::cin >> itemNumber;
        i = itemNumber - 1;
        std::cout << "Quantity: ";
        std::cin >> itemQuantity;
        menuItem[i].saveItemDetails(transactionFile);

        std::cout << "\nWould you like to add another item?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1. Yes\n2. No" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> billOpt;
        if (billOpt <= 0 | billOpt > 2) {
            std::cout << "Error. Please enter a valid number: ";
            std::cin >> billOpt;
        }
        if(billOpt == 2) { break; }
    }
    billingItem[i] = menuItem[i];
    billingItem[i].calculateVAT(count, itemQuantity);

    transactionFile.close();
```

the function within the implementation file:

```
void Item::calculateVAT(int count, int itemQuantity){
double total = 0.0;
double newItemPrice;

newItemPrice = itemPrice * itemQuantity;
total = newItemPrice + total;


//extra couts to see what is happening
std::cout << "ITEM QUANTITY" << itemQuantity <<"\n";
std::cout << "TOTAL" << total <<"\n";
}
```

what is produced when running the program:

```
Item: 2| Category: Meat| Description: Pork Chops| Price: £8
COUNT3
ITEM QUANTITY2
TOTAL16
Item: 3| Category: Meat| Description: Ribs| Price: £14
COUNT4
ITEM QUANTITY2
TOTAL28
```

Comment: "the program instead produces the total from itemPrice * itemQuantity" yes, that is what your code does. `total` is initialized to zero and then you have `newItemPrice = itemPrice * itemQuantity; total = newItemPrice + total;`. It is not quite clear what else you want. Please include a [mcve] and try to clarify the question

Comment: When inputting multiple items, the algorithm works out the `newItemPrice` however, total is getting overwritten rather than summing up multiple newItemPrices, I need some kind of variable which keeps adding up the newItemPrices in order to get a total at the end, like in the example of the output above, the second total should be 44 as it should do 16 + 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare total as static in the function so it is only initialized once.

```
 void Item::calculateVAT(int count, int itemQuantity){
static double total = 0.0;
double newItemPrice;

newItemPrice = itemPrice * itemQuantity;
total += newItemPrice ; // 


//extra couts to see what is happening
std::cout << "ITEM QUANTITY" << itemQuantity <<"\n";
std::cout << "TOTAL" << total <<"\n";
}
```

Another solution would be to declare a total variable in the main and modify your function signature.
That would imply printing total from your main.

calculateVAT function :

```
double Item::calculateVAT(int count, int itemQuantity)// No more void
{  
double total = 0.0; // this one only serves in the function scope
double newItemPrice;

newItemPrice = itemPrice * itemQuantity;
total = newItemPrice + total;


//extra couts to see what is happening
std::cout << "ITEM QUANTITY" << itemQuantity <<"\n";
std::cout << "TOTAL" << total <<"\n";

return total; // this number will add up in the main
}
```

Your main :

```
int main(){
    int i;
    Item billingItem[MAX_ORDER];
    Item menuItem[MAX_ORDER];
    int itemNumber;
    int itemQuantity;
    int billOpt;
    double total = 0.0; // this here will serve as the sum of all your items prices

    std::ofstream transactionFile;
    transactionFile.open("transactionFile.txt");
    int count = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_ORDER; i++) {
        std::cout << "Item number: ";
        std::cin >> itemNumber;
        i = itemNumber - 1;
        std::cout << "Quantity: ";
        std::cin >> itemQuantity;
        menuItem[i].saveItemDetails(transactionFile);

        std::cout << "\nWould you like to add another item?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1. Yes\n2. No" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> billOpt;
        if (billOpt <= 0 | billOpt > 2) {
            std::cout << "Error. Please enter a valid number: ";
            std::cin >> billOpt;
        }
        if(billOpt == 2) { break; }
    }
    billingItem[i] = menuItem[i];
   total +=  billingItem[i].calculateVAT(count, itemQuantity); // modified here``
   std::cout << "TOTAL" << total << std::endl;


    transactionFile.close();
```

For reference, I have made a simple code with a basic situation :

```
     void calculateVAT(int count, int itemQuantity) { // Static version, is initialized only once and then only gets updated

    static double total = 0;
    double newItemPrice;

    newItemPrice = 10 * itemQuantity;
    total += newItemPrice ;


    //extra couts to see what is happening
    std::cout << "ITEM QUANTITY " << itemQuantity << "\n";
    std::cout << "TOTAL from function  " << total << "\n";
}

double d_calculateVAT(int count, int itemQuantity) { // Non void version, returns a sum to a variable in the main

    double sum = 0;
    double newItemPrice;

    newItemPrice = 10 * itemQuantity;
    sum += newItemPrice;

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int itemQty = 5;
    double sum = 0; // if you want to call it from the main

    calculateVAT(0, 4); // void version with static - will update its total variable as 40
    calculateVAT(0, 7); // void version with static - will update its total variable as 40 + 70 = 110

    sum+=d_calculateVAT(0, 4); // double version - will return sum = 40
    sum+=d_calculateVAT(2, 7); // double version - will return sum + 70 = 110

    std::cout << "TOTAL from main " << sum << std::endl;

    while (1)
    { }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, maybe it's for another purpose, but I don't see the point of the variable "count" sent to calculateVAT, it's not used in the function.